# NGINX 301 remove .html from url, but not for files from a specific path (folder)

Tags: if-statement, nginx, redirect

In my `location /` directive I have added the following if statement to redirect all requests with the .html extension to the non-extension url:

```
if ($request_uri ~ ^/(.*)\.html) {
    return 301 /$1$is_args$args;
}
```

This works fine, but actual .html files are also being redirected which results in a 404. I want to avoid this by adding an exception for all requests if the the url contains the directory "/static/", but I am not sure how to do that. I tried to add the following if statement before the if statement above:

```
if ($request_uri ~ /static/) {

}
```

But I'm not sure what to put in it to stop it from executing the .html if statement. Return $host$request_uri doesn't work, unfortunately.

How would I be able to do this? I cannot use location directives due to limitations of my host. Everything is being done in in the `location /` directive.

Comment: You could use a negative lookahead assertion in the original regex: `$request_uri ~ ^/(?!static/)(.*)\.html`

Comment: @RichardSmith of course... I completely forgot about that. It works fine, thanks so much!